# I need help finding mean and standard deviation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation

Given that 80% of the values are less than 140 and 75% is less than 135. Distribution is a normal distribution. Find the mean and standard deviation.

Anyone can help to find and explaining a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\mu, \sigma$ for mean and deviation respectively, you have two equations of the following form: $P(X\leq x)=p$. When standardised, it becomes

$$P(X\leq x)=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=P\left(Z\leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

where $\Phi$ represents the CDF of the standard normal distribution. You can look up its value [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table), i.e. $\Phi(v_1)=0.8$ and $\Phi(v_2)=0.75$ and solve for $\mu,\sigma$ since you've a linear system of equations with two unknowns.